# Why is Kamtza blamed?

Tags: agada-stories-legends, maseches-gitin

The famous Gemara in Gittin says אקמצא ובר קמצא חרב ירושלים, that Jerusalem was destroyed because of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza. I understand why Bar Kamtza s getting some of the blame, but why is Kamtza blamed for Jerusalem’s destruction? He doesn’t even appear physically in the story

(I know you could say “Kamtza and Bar Kamtza” simply refers to the story as a whole because this is how it started, but I think there’s more behind it than just this

Comment: The Maharsha understands that they were father and son. The son assumed his father was working on making shalom. Perhaps he’s held responsible for not doing so. Or for the fact that he has such a son

Comment: Or that Kamtza encouraged "clique-ish", exclusive behavior among his friendships. (I forget who says this one.)

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers!

Comment: "_The famous Gemara in Gittin says אקמצא ובר קמצא חרב ירושלים, that Jerusalem was destroyed because of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza_ ... _why is Kamtza blamed for Jerusalem’s destruction?_" I don't understand the question.  That same famous Gemara also says אתרנגולא ותרנגולתא חרוב טור מלכא. To understand the part you quote as you do, a bigger question should be asked: Why are a  rooster and a hen blamed for the destruction of Tur Malka? My reading of both is: The incident involving X  and Y resulted in/led to the destruction of Z.

Comment: The same one who said "אקמצא ובר קמצא חרוב ירושלים", [said about the whole incident](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.56a.5?lang=bi&lang2=en): " ענוותנותו של רבי זכריה בן אבקולס, החריבה את ביתנו, ושרפה את היכלנו, והגליתנו מארצנו" ("The humility of Rabbi Zekharya ben Avkolas destroyed our Temple, burned our Sanctuary, and exiled us from our land
"). He seems to blame someone other than Kamtza, or Bar Kamtza.